# Difference between Fermi energy and ionisation energy

Tags: fermi-energy

At $T=0K$ what's the difference between Fermi energy and first ionisation energy?

Comment: Again, applying a concept from solid state physics and band structure to a single atom just doesn't work.

Comment: You should perhaps read this excellent introduction: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level